# I have issue with setting value of select input by jquery

Tags: jquery, select, input

Here is my Code saved on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vZK5n/)

I want to change by jQuery value of  item but it doesn't change.. when I try It from console with the same code it is OK.. please help..
Here it is always returning `-1` even I am setting by

```
 .val(value).change()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.change() is a listening event that listens for you to change the value of something.

To change the value of a form element then you will need:

```
$('input').val('changed value of a textbox');
```

If you are trying to change the value inside of HTML tags:

```
$('div').html('Changed html inside a div')
```

Also do not set properties of an HTML element using .attr()

```
//change this line
.attr("selected", "selected");

//into this line to select a dropdown item
.prop('selected', true);

//or this to unselect it
.prop('selected', false);
```

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 0):

To change a value, you don't need to do.

```
.change();
```

Just use

```
sta.find("select").val(myvalue);
```

If this isn't what you are looking for, please explain your problem. What do you mean by jQuery value? And what is your code trying to do? What you expect should happen but what did.

Borrowing from MonkeyZeus,

.change() is a listening event that listens for you to change the value of something.

Comment: Thank You for this answer but unfortunately I tried it already..here is explanation what I am trying to do.. I made annimated drop down list..when I click on one of items from that list I need to change value of input select tag so I can post it later. I know I could use input text but I waht this way because I don't know what is the problem..thanks again

Comment: @i.rijad Then please explain what are you trying to do and what and where is the problem. Your question isn't too informative or self explanatory neither is the code too simple to understand what you are trying.